# how to connect to MySQL(phphmyadmin) from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

When installing a fresh version of xampp I'm able to connect my js script to MySQL through the terminal.

```html
const mysql = require('mysql');

let con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    port:3307

  });

  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
  });
  
PS C:\login> node connection.js
Connected!
```

I've been trying another db which I have credentials for but it seems to be a problem when you have a password property in the con object. That it will not connect with a password :P What Im I doing wrong here?

```html
C:\login\connection.js:13
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\login\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\login\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\login\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\login\connection.js:12:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

Comment: You have to enable that to can connect without password as a root user,please check this https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/

Comment: are you sure that your mysql server is running? can you login via terminal using `mysql -u root -h localhost -p`

Comment: So the db I'm trying to connect to has another user name, it NOT root. 

const mysql = require('mysql');

  let con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "something",
    password: "something",
    port:3306
  
  });


  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
  });

and then I get the error message.

Comment: TCP connection was refused, hence we are not at auth phase jet. Rather ip or port are wrong. Check your mySQL if it is running an the port is the right one

Answer (score -1):

```
    var mysql = require("mysql");
        var con = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "localhost",
            user: "root",
            password: "",
            database:"xyz"
          });
          
          con.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Connected!");
          });
        
           PS C:\login> node connection.js
           Connected!
```